# Find matching value on another sheet and paste into next empty cell on that row

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling with this all day and I'm sure there's a really simple answer that I'm just not finding so hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

What I want to achieve is:

1. see if a value (R.BName) from sheet1 (wsResults) can be found in  column c of sheet2 (wsSchedule);
2. if found, paste a value from sheet1 (that I've already copied) into
   the next empty cell of that row;
3. if not found, insert a value into a specific cell in sheet1

The 2 issues I'm having are that:

1. If there is a match - the paste location is the last cell in row1 - *yes, I know that this be because my code has (1,columns.count) but I don't know how to get it to select the cell of the match!*
2. *"broker name not found on review schedule"* is being added to wsResults even if a match was on wsSchedule

Here is my defective code:

```
'copy result from wsresults
wsResults.range("R.Result").Copy

'find broker & add result to review schedule sheet
Dim wsSchedule As Worksheet
Dim rSearch As range
Dim c As range

Set wsSchedule = Worksheets("Review Schedule")
Set rSearch = wsSchedule.range("C5:C400")

For Each c In rSearch
    If c.Value = wsResults.range("R.BName").Value Then
        wsSchedule.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
        With wsResults
            .range("AP2:AP2").Value = "Broker name not found on review schedule"
        End With
    End If
Next c
```

Any assistance that can be offered would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, with your first issue, the row should be dynamic? That is to say, that the row you want to paste the value to isn't always going to be `row 1`?

Comment: As for your 2nd issue, try stepping through your code line by line (using `F8` in the VBE) and watch what is evaluated in the `Locals` window or by using the `Immidiate` window - This is useful for seeing what data your code is looking at/using and can make it very easy to identify errors in logic or references.

Comment: The dynamic value of `1`, in this case, should be `c.Row`, meaning the row in which the match was found. And, unless you anticipate finding a second and third match, consider placing an `Exit For` at that point.

Comment: Use `Find` rather than looping. What does "I've already copied" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you had in mind. Please try it.

```
Sub Test()
    ' 009

    Dim wsSchedule As Worksheet
    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim searchCrit As Variant
    Dim lastR As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Set wsSchedule = Worksheets("Review Schedule")
    Set wsResults = Worksheets("Results")
    ' try to access sheet values as little as possible: it's slow
    ' here, once is enough. No need to do it on every loop
    searchCrit = wsResults.Range("R.BName").Value

    With wsSchedule
        lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 5 To lastR
            If .Cells(R, "c").Value = searchCrit Then
                .Cells(R, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = wsResults.Range("R.Result")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    ' R will be <=lastR if a match was found
    If R > lastR Then
        wsResults.Cells(2, "AP").Value = "Broker name not found on review schedule"
    End If
End Sub
```

However, @SJR is right: using Find in place of the loop would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for this @variatus. The For R = 5 To rl is triggering an error as "rl" hasn't been defined? 

If a Find would be more efficient, would you be able to get me started on how it would look?

Also, the cell will always be AP2 on wsResults.... not sure if that makes any difference with the Find function!

Comment: Sorry about that. I usually call a row "R", first row "Rf" and the last row "Rl". In your code I tried to adapt to your nomenclature, where the last row would be "lastR". So, please change `Rl` to `lastR`.